# How to perform an api callout from sfdc into an external api?

Tags: soap-api, apexrest, callout

I'm trying to figure out a solution where I've to log some salesforce incidents into an external ticketing api. Can anyone here help me with how i can satisfy this requirement by performing an api call to the external api?

Comment: Can you provide details to the api? Is it REST? SOAP? Details will help

Comment: It supports both REST as well as SOAP.

Comment: @user13277 here you can see good tutorial how to do callout from salesforce  https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of many many many many ways to do a REST callout

Please ensure your endpoint is added to "Remote Site Settings" or the callout won't work.

```
        Integer timeout = 30; //In Seconds
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setTimeout(1000*timeout);

        String strEndpoint = 'http://myEndPoint';
        req.setEndpoint(strEndpoint);

        req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

        String authorizationHeader = ''; //Enter your token or user/pwd here
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

        req.setMethod('POST'); //Could be GET, or anything else

        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

        return res;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to use soap Api then you have to follow following
steps:-
1. consume wsdl file provide by  external api.
2.Make an instance of the class in which callout method reside. 
3.set  credential of the external api.
4.set your request.
5.make callout. 
6.get responce.
```